# Unity3d - Input.GetKey returns true more than once

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, event-handling, keyboard

I want to move my object on scene using keyboard inputs. To do this work, I create an empty game object and attach a `.cs` file to it. Code of this `.cs` file is below :

```
void Update()
{
     if (Input.GetKey ("up") ) {
         Debug.Log("up");
     }
     else if (Input.GetKey ("down") ) {
         Debug.Log("down");
     }
 }
```

I press up key **only once**, it writes output string on condole 7 times. Shouldn't I use this function to handle keyboard input?

Comment: Perhaps `Input.GetKeyDown` is what you're after?

Comment: `GetKeyDown` returns true only one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html

Returns true while the user holds down the key identified by name. **Think auto fire**.

If you look at the input class you can find other functions which will be more useful.

Comment: `GetKeyDown` returns only one time. Thanks.

Comment: Unity manual is pretty good, don't neglect it. It should always be your first option, not your last.